# Programs in different desktop environments

Tags: installation, desktop-environments

I have a question which might be defined as a "nooby" one.

Do programs that work on Ubuntu 13.04 Unity **NECESSARILY** work on other desktop environments (such as Lubuntu)?

And by programs I mean... Well, programs and packages and all that. I don't want trouble with my printer/scanner and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all programs that work on Unity will work in Lubuntu, except for programs which for some weird reason require Unity to be running (read: almost none).

Comment: Thank you for answering! Would all the tutorials for Ubuntu work under any desktop environment? (For instance, enabling trim support or stuff like that).

Comment: @Crake well, yes, Lubuntu and Ubuntu both have the same underlying system, the only difference really is the desktop environment (and that can be changed by installing the desktop environment's package).

Comment: @Crake BTW, you can always install the ubuntu-desktop package in Lubuntu to have Unity as a desktop environment option (during login there'll be an a drop-down list of desktop environments).

Answer (score 1):

All Ubuntu packages will run in any desktop environment. But at the times you need animations you will face the difference. Because The official Unity, KDE are for performance + Animations like graphics and etc but XFCE , LXDE are mainly designed for performance.

so bottom line is applications are nothing to do with Desktop Environments in the matter of performance.

Comment: He's not talking about performance, he is wondering whether applications working in Unity will work in Lubuntu.

Comment: He mentioned something like don't want any trouble.. ..that's means he want good performance while running the application. That's how I understood